# Using pointer functions to emulate member functions in C structs

Tags: c

So just for the sake if having ''fun'' I decided to emulate `C++` member functions in `C` using pointer functions. Here is a simple code:

obj.h:

```
#ifndef OBJ_H
#define OBJ_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Obj{
    struct pObjVar* pVar;

    void (*read)(struct Obj*);
    void (*set) (struct Obj*, int);
};

struct Obj* newObj();
void deleteObj(struct Obj** obj);

#endif
```

obj.c:

```
#include "obj.h"

void readValue(struct Obj* this_);
void setValue (struct Obj* this_, int mValue_);

struct pObjVar{
    int mValue;
};

struct Obj* newObj(){
    struct Obj* tmp  = (struct Obj*)     malloc(sizeof(struct Obj));
    tmp->pVar        = (struct pObjVar*) malloc(sizeof(struct pObjVar));

    tmp->pVar->mValue = 0;
    tmp->read = readValue;
    tmp->set  = setValue;

    return tmp;
}

void deleteObj(struct Obj **obj){
    free((*obj)->pVar); (*obj)->pVar = NULL;
    free((*obj)); *obj = NULL;
}

void readValue(struct Obj *this_){
    printf("Value = %d\n",this_->pVar->mValue);
}

void setValue(struct Obj *this_, int mValue_){
    this_->pVar->mValue = mValue_;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "obj.h"

int main(void)
{
    struct Obj* a = newObj();
    a->set(a, 10);
    a->read(a);
    deleteObj(&a);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
>./a.out
 Value = 10
```

In doing this, however, I figured I had to emulate the role of implicit `this` pointer by explicitly passing it to my member functions. This works fine, I guess, except that it makes the whole thing look weird!

If I wanted to pass the object, why would implement the functions as member functions? The only answer I found to it was maybe in cases where you would want to have a unified interface but various implementations? (something *similar* to `C++` virtual functions?)

What are (if any) some other reasons to emulate member functions? Also, is there any way to get around passing the explicit `this_` pointer at all?

**EDIT**: There was problem in the original code when passing the object. I was using `&a` by mistake for the `read/set` functions. You would only need it for the `deleteObj` if you want to set the pointer to `NULL` internally.

Comment: You are passing the _address_ of the pointer to the functions, i.e. `Obj **`. Skip the `&` in the function calls.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You are correct. Please see my edit

Comment: I once had to maintain a legacy project using a similar approach, with a complex inheritance hierarchy, and the added perversion of using opaque typedef'ed int values instead of pointers to structures. Needless to say that it was a nightmare to debug/maintain !

Comment: You should make the 'methods' `readValue` and `setValue` static so that they  become local to `obj.c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another way of writing:

```
#define member(FUNC, ...) FUNC(this_, ## __VA_ARGS__)
int reader(struct Obj *_this) {
  member(read, a, b, c);
  member(getch);
  return 0;
}
```

This can be used for implementing interfaces, inheritance and many C++ features, which were implemented like this in C with Classes times. In Linux kernel, file operations are implemented like this. File structure stores pointers to functions, so that each file system can store it's own system call handlers that operate on/with the data in the structure.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this automatically in C. The standard preprocessor is not competent enough to do the transformations.

There is also now way for a function to find out that it was called like `a->func(10)`. Inside the function it is just `func(10)`.

When Bjarne Stroustrup started designing C++, he wrote a special preprocessor/compiler [Cfront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) for this.

In reality, C++ doesn't really store pointers to (non-virtual) functions. It just transforms `a->set(10)` to something like `struct_Obj_set(a, 10)` while compiling the code.